# Access database not updating

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I am trying to connect to access 2010 database using the following string connection. But, it wont make any changes in the database.

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Program Files\\LogEntry\\LogEntry.accdb; Persist Security Info = False;");

conn.Open();

String text2send = "INSERT INTO TLC(Name,Department,Position,VisitDate,InTime,OutTime,Purpose,HelpedBy,Campus,HelpCode) VALUES(" + name + "," + department + "," + position + "," + date + "," + hourIn + "," + hourOut + "," + purpose + "," + helpedBy + "," + campus + "," + helpcode + ");";

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(text2send,conn);
conn.Close();
```

Edit:
This is the edited code that I used with Parameter query.

```
 String name = nameTextbox.Text;
 String department = departmentCBox.Text;
 String purpose = purposeTextbox.Text;
 String position = positionCBox.Text;
 String date = inDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
 String helpCode = helpCodeCBox.Text;
 String hourOut = ""+OutHour.Text+":"+OutMin+" "+OutMeredian;
 String helpedBy= "";
 String campus= "";
 String helpcode= "";
 String hourIn = "" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh") + ":" + 

 DateTime.Now.ToString("mm") + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("tt");

 OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Program Files\\LogEntry\\LogEntry.accdb; Persist Security Info = False;");
            conn.Open();


 String text2send = "Insert Into TLC([Name],[Department],[Position],[VisitDate],[InTime],[OutTime],[Purpose],[HelpedBy],[Campus],[HelpCode]) VALUE(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";

 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(text2send,conn);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", name);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Department", department);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Position", position);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Purpose", purpose);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("HelpedBy", helpedBy);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Campus", campus);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("HelpCode", helpcode);

 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 conn.Close();
```

Comment: you never execute the command

Comment: Also, change that to a parameter query before it all falls apart.

Comment: At a glance, it should be `VALUES (?` not `VALUE(?`

Comment: Similarly, MS Access is rarely happy with empty strings `helpedBy= "";`

Comment: Your parameter count does not match your field count and the order is different. You must use the same number and order for parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` after your command is created and before you close the connection

Comment: Mucker,Thank you for the prompt reply. I have added that and now it says syntax error in the insert into statement. Does this mean the database fields do not match with the text i am sending?

Comment: I assume `Name`, `Department`, etc. are strings, but you don't surround your string variables with apostrophes, such as `VALUES('" + name + "',"`.  You're better off following Remou's advice and using a parametrized query, since that query will still die if you pass in `Conan O'Brien` as a name.

Comment: Name may be a string, but it is also a reserved word therefore [Name]

Comment: @Remou - yeah, `Name` was a bad example.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Not particularly, you had to choose from all those undelimited dates :)

Comment: name, department, position and all those are variables. I have to retrieve text from a textbox and put it in the database. I have changed it to..    <String text2send = "INSERT INTO TLC(Name,Department,Position,VisitDate,InTime,OutTime,Purpose,HelpedBy,Campus,HelpCode) VALUES(@name,@department,@position,@date,@hourIn,@hourOut,@purpose,@helpedBy,@campus,@helpcode);";>

Comment: @msmucker0527 Could you look at my code one more time? I have used the parameter queery and it still gives me syntax error.

Comment: @ShashiDongur Where are you adding the parameters to the command object? Edit your post to show your new code underneath the original code.